# Updating Current FirebaseUser across Flutter TabView

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Let's assume I have the home page with 4 tabs. One of the tab is a login page with Firebase login and 3 other tabs need to know if the user is logged-in or a guest.

Below is the code of the Stateful home page.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((FirebaseUser user) {
      currentUser = user;
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: allTabs,
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
        title: Text(
          "app title",
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ItemsList(currentUser),
          CategoriesList(),
          currentUser == null ? LoginPage() : ProfileWidget(),
          NewsfeedWidget(currentUser ),
          ItemsList(currentUser , showOnlyFav),
          AboutUs(),
        ],
        controller: _tabController,
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Question:**

Even when I login successfully from the login page, other tabs are not reflecting the current user. The currentUser value is always null.

How should I make the login details instant update acros all pages whenever there is a login/logout?

UPDATE: I have tried wrapping TabBarView inside StreamBuilder. But still the same and also the pages get refreshed very often.

Comment: *The currentUser value is always null.* - In the other tabs it will be null because you pass the initial null currentUser to those tabs, but when the login state changes you don't recreate them(and give them the newly update currentUser value). *How should I make the login details instant update...* - one way to do it would be to wrap the TabBarView in a StreamBuilder widget and use the FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged as its stream.

Comment: I tried that and it makes all hte pages to refresh multiple times, which is not loooking good. Also it does not help to solve.

Comment: Did you implement it like this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/cce919f031d21c02fe33da328b2fc012 ?

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: @Luksprog : It works great. Thanks. But do I take the updated new value outside the body within the same StatefulWidget class? Let see to update floating bar based on the user or guest.

Comment: I got it. Please add your solution as the answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your current code in a StreamBuilder based on the stream from FirebaseAuth. This way your layout has access to the user whenever its login status changes:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: allTabs,
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
        title: Text(
          "app title",
        ),
      ),
      body: 
      StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          return TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              ItemsList(snapshot.data),
              CategoriesList(),
              snapshot.data == null ? LoginPage() : ProfileWidget(),
              NewsfeedWidget(snapshot.data),
              ItemsList(snapshot.data , showOnlyFav),
              AboutUs(),
            ],
          controller: _tabController,
      ),}
    );
  }
```